# PHP code is being commented out after jQuery's $.get() function

Tags: php, jquery, comments

Before blasting me, this is not a duplicate answer. None of the suggested or googled helped me out.

The problem is the following. I have a .php file which I use jQuery's $.get() function to include a .php file which counts me the files on a directory.

The code was working normally, I did not modify it. It seems it was a server permission or something that broke the code.

So when I execute the $.get() code the .php code is commented out. I tried checking file permissions and they have the "Execute" attribute active. I have tried setting both at 755, and 555 to no avail.

The snippet of code is as follows:

```
$.get("/"+pathManga+"mangacounter4.php?dir="+dir+dp_sel, function(result) {
            $('#contentLoaded').html(result);
```

[image: This is the result taken from the web debugger]

And this is the .php code:

```
<?php
$directory = "{$_GET['dir']}/";
    $backer = '';
    if (glob("$directory*.png") != false)
    {
    $filecount = count(glob("$directory*.png"));
    $i = 1;
    while($i<=$filecount)
    {
        $backer .= "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
        $i++;
    }
    }
if(isset($_GET['dp']))
{
    echo('R. Page<select name="pages" id="pages_r" onchange="gen(this.value,document.mangy.chapters.value,\'\',\'\',\'ns_trigger\');">');
    echo($backer);
    echo('</select><br/>
         L. Page<select name="pages" id="pages_l" onchange="gen(this.value,document.mangy.chapters.value,\'\',\'\',\'ns_trigger\');">');
    echo($backer);
    echo('</select>');  
    echo('<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("pages_l").options[1].selected="selected";</script>');
}
else
{   
    echo('<select name="pages" id="pages" onchange="gen(this.value,document.mangy.chapters.value,\'\',\'\',\'ns_trigger\');">');
    echo($backer);
    echo('</select>');  
}


?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a million!

Comment: What do you get if you visit the mangacounter4.php file directly fro your browser address bar?

Comment: What code (html or other) do you have around the php? (if any)

Comment: Are you using some php framework?? maybe that mangacounter4.php is preprocessed by the framework.  Did you change .htmaccess ??

Comment: did you comment the code like this before? maybe cache? have you tried this in the get url "/"+pathManga+"mangacounter4.php?dir="+dir+dp_sel+"&t="+new Date().getTime()

Comment: Thanks people. 

user574632: When I visit it, the file gets downloaded.

thePav: No code. That's the complete file.

Luis Siquot: I'm trying out a code in Drupal 7. I asked this question before on their site. Seems it doesn't matter https://drupal.org/node/2268629

pecci: Yup. Just tried it, and it didn't work.

Comment: The PHP file gets downloaded when you directly access it in the browser? It seems like either the server doesn't run PHP (forcing a download of an unidentified file) or there's something in the config of the server forcing a PHP download... either way, looks like a server config issue.

Comment: Yes, see the above comment. The server is not processing the php.

Comment: Thanks people! Let me see if I can contact (currently running on hostgator) tech support.

Comment: I am sure it is a new bad rule on .htaccess on the same dir or on one of its parents. Please tag usernames with @ in order to better follow this.

Comment: briefly rename .htaccess to test (may afect other things) Post it here.

Comment: @LuisSiquot: http://pastebin.com/C4ZseyWf

Thanks a million. 

I went to support and they didn't know how to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems I've found the solution. There was a .htaccess file I had on one of the folders. I deleted the file, and everything started to work! :D

Thanks people for all the help!